# nginx-ingress reverseproxy backend subpath

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

In a non Ingress Setup I can configure a `proxy_pass` to a subpath of the upstreams server.

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name myapp.example.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://10.0.0.12/myapp/dashboards/bar/;
    }
  }
```

How do I reconfigure a nginx-ingress like that? I've tried to do the following.

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /myapp/dashboards/bar/$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - myapp.example.com
      secretName: myapp.example.com-tls
  rules:
    - host: myapp.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              serviceName: backendservicename
              servicePort: 80
```

calling against the ingress I get

```
curl --insecure  https://myapp.example.com/ -I
HTTP/2 404
date: Fri, 20 Nov 2020 15:39:45 GMT
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: I believe the annotation [`app-root`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/#app-root) is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hey @schmichri, it solved your issue?

Comment: I could check on a short notice but it hasn't been working. I need to check in detail again.